# How to give a batch of frames to the model in pytorch c++ api?

Tags: c++, pytorch, torch

I've written a code to load the pytorch model in C++ with help of the PyTorch C++ Frontend api. I want to give a batch of frames to a pretrained model in the C++ by using `module->forward(batch_frames)`. But it can forward through a single input. 
How can I give a batch of inputs to the model?

A part of code that I want to give the batch is shown below:

```
 cv::Mat frame;
 vector<torch::jit::IValue> frame_batch;

 // do some pre-processes on each frame and then add it to the frame_batch

 //forward through the batch frames
 torch::Tensor output = module->forward(frame_batch).toTensor();
```

Comment: Do you have any solution? I've asked the same question at https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-forward-a-batch-of-type-vector-example/41267/2

Comment: Not yet! I thought the problem would be solved by updating the libtorch but nothing happened. Thank you for sharing your issue. @Markus

Comment: My question got answered at the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I used a function in c++ to concatenate images and make a batch of images. Then convert the batch into the torch::tensor and feed the model using the batch. A part of code is given below:

```
// cat 2 or more images to make a batch
cv::Mat batch_image;
cv::vconcat(image_2, images_1, batch_image);

// do some pre-process on image
auto input_tensor_batch = torch::from_blob(batch_image.data, {size_of_batch, image_height, image_width, 3});
input_tensor_batch = input_tensor_batch.permute({0, 3, 1, 2});

//forward through the batch frames
 torch::Tensor output = module->forward({input_tensor_batch}).toTensor();
```

Note that put the { } in the forward-pass function!

Comment: it'd be nicer if you could also add that `vconcat` is actually ``` cv::vconcat``` in opencv.

Comment: Edited! Thanks @Rika .

Answer (score 2):

You can create a batch of tensors in libtorch using a variety of ways.
Here is one of these ways:
Using Torch::TensorList:
Since `torch::TensorList` is `ArrayRef`, you can not directly add any tensors to it, therefore first create a vector of tensors and then create your `TensorList` using that verctor:

```cpp
// two already processed tensor!
auto tensor1 = torch::randn({ 1, 3, 32, 32 });
auto tensor2 = torch::randn({ 1, 3, 32, 32 });
// using a tensor list
std::vector<torch::Tensor> tensor_vec{ tensor1, tensor2 };
torch::TensorList tensor_list{ tensor_vec};

auto batch_of_tensors = torch::cat(tensor_lst);
auto out = module->forward({batch_of_tensors}).toTensor();
```

Or you could do :

```cpp
auto batch_of_tensors = torch::cat({ tensor_vec});
```

or

```cpp
auto batch_of_tensors = torch::cat({ tensor1, tensor2});
```